# Disable obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm currently building a robot that will navigate in a building. It will have odometry for localization and IR range sensor (with data send as LaserScan) for obstacle detection. However I don't want it to avoid the obstacle, I just want it to stop when it detects an obstacle.

How can I disable obstacle avoidance in the navigation stack (I still require the navigation_stack for the global pathfinding) ?

I was considering setting marking and clearing to false in the costmap_commons_params.yml. Ex:
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: sharp, marking: false, clearing: false}

As I understand it, the sensor will draw nothing on the costmap and therefor the robot will not try to avoid the obstacle. Am I correct ?

Is there an other simpler way to do that ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201824/disable-obstacle-avoidance/) by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-01-27**:
Do you do the stopping or do you want the nav_stack to do it? In other words: Would it be OK for you if the navstack is blind?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-27**:
Which distribution are you using?

**Comment by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on 2015-01-27**:
Thanks for your answers.
@dornhege: Yes I want the navigation stack to be blind. The controller will listen to the LaserScan thread and do the stopping.
@David Lu: I use Indigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easier way to disable the obstacle avoidance would be to remove the obstacles layer from the plugins parameter.

To do this, in your global_costmap.yaml, add a parameter called plugins.

```
plugins:
    - {name: static_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on 2015-01-28**:
How would you do that ?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-29**:
When you start move_base, does it say anything about using pre-hydro parameters?

**Comment by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on 2015-01-29**:
Thank you for your answer. I can't launch the move_base node for some reason. I'll open an other question on this one (ERROR: cannot launch node of type [move_base/move_base]: can't locate node [move_base] in package [move_base] even if I succeed in launching the file move_base_0.3_to_0.2.launch)

**Comment by [Zeken](https://answers.ros.org/users/41317/zeken/) on 2019-09-20**:
Hi, I know this is thread is very old, but can I ask is it as easy as putting in this plugin into the global_costmap.yaml? What does this plugin actually do?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-09-23**:
Please open your own question.